# Problem with different types depends on boolean value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

It's my first post on stackoverflow so I'm asking for understand.

```
type InputProps =
   | ({
        isTextArea: false;
        label: string;
     } & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'>)
   | ({
        isTextArea: true;
        label: string;
     } & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'textarea'>);


const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ isTextArea, label, ...props }) => {
   return (
      <div className='w-full'>
         <label htmlFor=''></label>
         {isTextArea ? <textarea {...props} /> : <input {...props} />}
      </div>
   );
};

export default Input;
```

[Problems in input and textarea element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfvaZ.png)

How can I properly define the types depends on boolean variable *isTextArea*?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it shows that typescript error even after type guarding. But I got a solution.
Here are the code:

```
// UTILITY FUNCTIONS AND ITS TYPES
type TOmit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

function omit<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): TOmit<T, K> {
  const result = { ...obj };
  for (const key of keys) {
    delete result[key];
  }
  return result;
}

type InputProps = {
  label: string;
} & (
  | ({
      isTextArea: false;
    } & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"input">)
  | ({
      isTextArea: true;
    } & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"textarea">)
);

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <label htmlFor="">{props.label}</label>
      {props.isTextArea ? (
        <textarea {...omit(props, ["isTextArea", "label"])} />
      ) : (
        <input {...omit(props, ["isTextArea", "label"])} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I got this solution from a Youtube video by Josh Tried Coding. You can check his video also if you want. His video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9i38FPugxB8&t=352s